# Subgroup for Office365/SP Front-End questions

Tags: discussion

I have had some conversations behind the scenes with people into CSR, NG etc.

There is no real online place for a Office365 Front-End/Apps/AddIn Community

- StackExchange/SharePoint doesn't cover the topic well enough
  (*and to be honest I am about to sign off because after a year I bring more than I get from it*)
- ITUnity is too generic
- The Yammer groups suck in keeping track (*personal opinion*)
- NGOfficeFabricUI (Slack community) is too specific

Would a **O365Front-End** subcommunity be possible here? Or are there other places?

Comment: I agree there is a void, it is a grey area among several SE sites.

Comment: I feel this is the right place, is there something @Danny Engelman that we can do in your opinion to drive more adoption or get attention to more knowledgeable eyes looking at these?

Comment: hard-to-find information!

Comment: If this was the right place (and not just for front-end scope), the SP gurus and other experienced developers would still be here.

Comment: It's free for everyone to start a proposal on http://area51.stackexchange.com/ - so why not give it a shot?

Comment: That's going to be a nightmare drawing the line and flagging/closing posts between sharepoint and o365 apps. I see so much confusion there. I say bring all the o365 questions here!

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, any updates regarding this? I think it would be great to have a section for front-end developers to exchange info and communicate.

Comment: Nah, I don't have the power. Maybe the common thought among admins is that the new Microsoft world should be ruled by .Net developers who learned Front-End yesterday and think TypeScript is not JavaScript. You don't see much effort from Microsoft either to get those 100 Million Front-End developers with way more expereince into this "new" Microsoft world.